How to save the end-to-end encrypted Facebook messages? And search in old messages (after the encryption update)?
There was a Facebook update, i believe March 27, 2024, which made all messages end-to-end encrypted.
Facebook offers to save the messages via Messenger.com on desktop - Privacy & safety -
End-to-end encrypted chats - Secure storage - Download secure storage data, however that downloads 100 messages. I have thousands.
Is there any other way? I tried to Print, save PDF, nothing works, everything captures the current page with 5 messages on it. On Android I dont even have an option to save anything. Anybody has any idea, please??
And, my second question. IS there any way to search in the old messages, before the update? It is completely impossible to search in any message before March 26. Additionally, I can only search via Android messenger app, Search in Conversation. On desktop Ctrl+F shortcut doesnt bring up anything but the currently already scrolled and visible in messenger text..
